# ffmpeg: замена аудиодорожек в множестве видеофайлов на другие аудиодорожки из той же папки

Tags: cmd, bat, ffmpeg

Доброго времени суток! Итак, у меня есть папка с множеством видеофайлов в формате mkv, которые все содержат **нежелательную** аудиодорожку. Также, в этой же папке у меня есть такое же количество аудиофайлов в формате ac3, который являются **желательными** аудиодорожками для видеофайлов и которое все имеют такое же название, как у видеофайлов. 
Мне нужно чтоб ffmpeg автоматически заменил аудиодорожки в каждом видеофайле, в качестве источника взяв аудиофайлы с таким же именем из той же папки.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r "входой каталог" %%I in (*.mkv) do (
ffmpeg -i "%%I" -i "%%~dpnI.ac3" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -y "выходной каталог\%%~nI.mkv"
)
```